# Complexity of adding n elements to a LinkedList using a loop

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, big-o, time-complexity

Let's say I do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    list.add(i);
}
```

The complexity of this should be O(n<sup>2</sup>) if there is no tail pointer, right? (Because each insertion would be O(n) and I'm doing n insertions?) But if there was a tail pointer it would be O(n), correct?

Comment: ... as long as it is adding to the tail, not the start.

Comment: Ok thanks. And if I was doing m insertions would I say O(m*n) or is it just better to say it as O(n^2)? @Lucas

Comment: If you mean doing m insertion operations (at a fixed position) instead of `list.add` inside the loop, then it will do m*n things. In this case it is O(n) - or if you include m, O(m*n).

Comment: If your insertion operation does not depend on the length of the list, or you lists length does not change every iteration, then it is just O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct. With a tail pointer, you can append a value to the linked list in time O(1) by going to the element pointed at by the tail pointer, updating the "next" pointer, and then updating the tail to point to the new element. The total runtime will be O(n).

On the other hand, without a tail pointer, finding the last element of the list so that you can update its pointer will take time O(n) because all elements of the list must be scanned. Therefore, the total runtime will be O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Hope this helps!